# What can i do for SMS encryption for security purpos

Tags: java, php, node.js, encryption

I am trying to encrypting data(SMS text within 160 characters ) using the AES128 algorithm but data size become larger then actual data in character count. I need to implement a way to encrypt data(SMS Text) within 160 character because if SMS text length become more than 160 user will charge for 2 SMS.For example:I want to send a message from a financial application to It's user  wich orginal text is less than 160 character.My wish is to encrypt this message but cannot be larger than 160 character.

Comment: Sane encryption schemes will always yield an encrypted text larger than the input text (for a number of reasons, among them; you want to validate the original message was successfully recovered - that requires a mechanism to perform the validation and that requires space - another is producing the same # of characters as input is an "easy" vector for cryptanalysis). How much security do you need and how familiar are you with math?

Comment: I was going to suggest running your data through compression like GZIP before encryption, but with input as small as 160 bytes you're again likely to have your output larger than the input in some, if not most, cases.

Comment: @Sammitch It's also somewhat dangerous as the resulting size may leak information about the contents of the plaintext message. There are things like Format Preserving Encryption or FPS, but beware of the steep learning curve associated with it. Usually it is performed on smaller message sizes.

Comment: This SMS text will contain  secure information which will decrypt from server and then perform task for this user.

Comment: If anything I would suggest treating SMS messages as packets. Encoded in base64 to be 7-bit safe you would 120 data bytes per SMS "packet", shave off a couple bytes for header metadata, and then just send as many packets as are needed to transmit messages of any length encrypted with actual encryption.

Comment: @sammitch, you are not in my domain. This SMS will com to my server throw user's mobile default sms app.this SMS should be encrypted to this user also.

Answer (score 2):

1. Encryption is not compression. Encryption will normally result in LONGER text (otherwise everyone would use encrypted text all the time since it would save space).
2. Normal compression algorithms have some overhead size to them. They usually have to store a little bit of information that explains how the data can be safely decompressed later. Think of it this way - you have a string like "I like red. I like green. I like blue." A compression algorithm could say, "The phrase 'I like ' is repeated a lot, so I will replace that with "A", and then "red" and "green" and "blue" will be reduced to "X", "Y", and "Z", respectively. The compressed string becomes "AXAYAZ". Now, if you just sent "AXAYAZ" to the decompression routine, it could not be decompressed as-is because there is nothing that tells the decompression routine what each letter means. So usually there has to be a dictionary along with the compressed data, like: "A=I like,X=red,Y=blue,Z=green,AXAYAZ". As with most data formats, there's usually extra bytes to store the expected lengths of the data (so the decompression algorithm knows that A is "I like" and not "I like,X=red,Y=blue,Z=green", etc). On top of that, you often have timestamps and/or checksums (so you know when compressed data is corrupted).

When you're dealing with compressing a 1-megabyte string, overhead of a few kilobytes of data makes a lot of sense. But if your original string is 160 bytes, then the overhead/header/dictionary can be long enough that the final compressed file is bigger than the original. If you want to see how this looks, create a 1-byte file in Notepad and try to zip it.

3. All that said, if your messages are mostly similar (e.g. they are made up mostly of a fixed, short list of words like "MESSAGE", "ANSWER", "USER", or whatever), then you could potentially ENCODE your message. So you could turn "ANSWER THIS MESSAGE" into "A9X", for example. But encoding is NOT encryption. You could encode first to reduce the size of the message and then use encryption so that you would have an encrypted message that was smaller. However, that will ONLY work if you have a fixed list of words like that. Otherwise, encoding would not work for you. So if your messages are completely custom each time, then you probably would not have any way of doing this unless you could transmit the compression header/footer/dictionary separately somehow.

All that said, if the STRENGTH of your encryption wasn't important, you could look at some FPE techniques. Check out this answer for some examples:
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32090/which-cryptography-technique-does-not-increase-the-size-of-the-plain-data

Comment: Just for laughs I ran the 38-byte string `I like red. I like green. I like blue.` through the DEFLATE algorithm. It shortened it to 34 bytes.